# C segfaults stemming from reading standard input and then manipulating that data

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stdout, stdin

I have a problem where I am trying to read words from stdin and then manipulate it and then print to stdout later. However, when I don't redirect the stdout, it segfaults at 2 places, if I'm trying to printf any words that I have scanned from STDIN (I can use puts() to display information to console that's fine though) OR when I try to access the inherent data from each words (like I strcasecmpr() that I used later). Can anyone here help?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int aflag = 0;
    int bflag = 0;
    int cflag = 0;
    int c;

    //int opteval
    Instruction head= NULL;
    Instruction first= NULL;
    init(head);
    puts("Init for head done");
    //While there are more instructions
    char line [128];
    printf("SdlJ");
    int numlines = 0;
    first = head; //Setting pointer to first instruction in list CHECK THIS LATER
    int index = 0;
    int rc = 0;
    char instr[20], r1[300], r2[300], r3[300], r4[300];
    instr[0] = '\0';
    r1[0] = '\0';
    r2[0] = '\0';
    r3[0] = '\0';
    r4[0] = '\0';

    while( fgets ( line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL){
        puts(line);
        rc = sscanf(line, "%s %s %s %s %s", instr,r1,r2,r3,r4);
        if(rc == 4)
            puts("here");
        puts(instr);
        //printf("sfds%ssfsd", instr); SEGFAULT CASE 1: THIS WOULD SEG FAULT IF I UNCOMMENTED IT
        //return 1;
        chooseOp(head, instr);
        createReg(head, r1, 0);

        if(r2[0] != '=' && r2[0] != '\0')
            createReg(head, r2, 1);

        if(r3[0] != '='&& r3[0] != '\0')
            createReg(head, r3, 2);

        if(rc < 5)
            createReg(head, r4, 3);
        puts("here");
        Instruction next = NULL;
        init(next);
        numlines++;
        head->next = next;
        next->prev = head;
        head = next;
        //Point prevs's next to new head, and that heads prev to the previous head.
    }
}

void chooseOp(Instruction head, char* token){
    //Simple function to find the opcode responsible for this instruction
    //printf("sfdjls");

    puts("segfaulting");
    // SEGFAULT PLACE 2, IT SEGFAULTS RIGHT AT THIS STRCASECMP BELOW
    if(strcasecmp("nop", token) == 0){
        head->opcode= NOP;
        head->ismem=1;
        head->latency = 1;
    }
    else if(strcasecmp("addI", token) == 0){
        head->opcode= ADDI;
        head->ismem=1;
        head->latency = 1;
    }
    else if(strcasecmp("add", token) == 0){
        head->opcode= ADD;
        head->ismem=1;
        head->latency = 1;
    }
    else if(strcasecmp("subI", token) == 0){
        head->opcode= SUBI;
        head->ismem=1;
        head->latency = 1;
    }
    else if(strcasecmp("sub", token) == 0){
        head->opcode= SUB;
        head->ismem=1;
        head->latency = 1;
    }
    else if(strcasecmp("mult", token) == 0){
        head->opcode= MULT;
        head->ismem=1;
        head->latency = 3;
    }
    else if(strcasecmp("div", token) == 0){
        head->opcode= DIV;
        head->ismem=1;
        head->latency = 3;
    }
    else if(strcasecmp("load", token) == 0){
        head->opcode= LOAD;
        head->ismem=0;
        head->latency = 5;
    }
    else if(strcasecmp("loadI", token) == 0){
        head->opcode= LOADI;
        head->ismem=0;
        head->latency = 1;
    }
    else if(strcasecmp("loadAO", token) == 0){
        head->opcode= LOADAO;
        head->ismem=0;
        head->latency = 5;
    }
    else if(strcasecmp("loadAI", token) == 0){
        puts("here23");
        head->opcode= LOADAI;
        head->ismem=0;
        head->latency = 5;
    }
    else if(strcasecmp("store", token) == 0){
        head->opcode= STORE;
        head->ismem=0;
        head->latency = 5;
    }
    else if(strcasecmp("storeAO", token) == 0){
        head->opcode= STOREAO;
        head->ismem=0;
        head->latency = 5;
    }
    else if(strcasecmp("storeAI", token) == 0){
        head->opcode= STOREAI;
        head->ismem=0;
        head->latency = 5;
    }
    else if(strcasecmp("output", token) == 0){
        head->opcode= OUTPUT;
        head->ismem=0; //Need to ask prof about this
        head->latency = 1;
    }

    puts("here");
}
```

This is an example of what I'm supposed to read:

```
 loadI 1024     => r0 
 loadI 0    => r1 
 storeAI r1     => r0, 0
```

And so on.

Please help.

EDIT: here's my code for init(head)

```
void init(Instruction head)
{
    head = (Instruction) malloc(sizeof(struct Command));
    head->opcode = 0;
    head->next = NULL;
    head->prev = NULL;
    head->ismem = -1;
    head->firstReg = NULL;
    head->secondReg = NULL;
    head->outputReg1 = NULL;
    head->outputReg2 = NULL;
    head->successors = NULL;
    //head->depends = NULL;
    head->numInstructions = 0;
    //head->lineNum = -1;
    head->priority = 0;
    head->numdepends = 0;
    head->cycle = 0;
    head->delay = -1;
}
```

Comment: Here's a tip: Build with debug information (add the `-g` flag to GCC) and run your program in a debugger ([here's the GNU debugger manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/)). The debugger will stop at the location of the crash, it will let you examine the function call stack (GDB command `bt`) and let you walk up the call-stack to your code (the `up` command). There you can `print` the values of variables to help you understand what happened. At least edit your question to include the function call-stack.

Comment: "...it segfaults at 2 places" I don't suppose you'd be willing to tell us where those two places *are* ? Mark them with comments *in the question code* please. And if I had to guess I would surmise all the code you're *not* showing us (specifically all the linked list functions like `init()` hat are not taking their pointers *by-address* are allocating (and likely leaking) memory, leaving the passed parameters untouched. This is C, not C++ so passing a pointer by-reference isn't an option. I see nothing that suggests any of them are being passed correctly.

Comment: Post the code for `init` please. And verify *this is C code, right?* And shall we assume `Instruction` is a pointer-type conveniently obfuscated in a typedef?

Comment: Instructions are all pointers to structs, I typedef'd that way, but you're saying that it might not recognize this style? Sorry I've always just passed the general pointer, because I saw that it takes the address of the pointer ayway

Comment: @user2353398 I can all-but-guarantee you they're not being initialized correctly. And as a side note, you've set aside 1220 chars to parse a string that by-definition can only be 128 chars wide. Seems a little overt .

Comment: @WhozCraig, that is exactly what I did. And this is C code. And Joachim Pileborg, I'll do that too

Comment: As I suspected, `init()` is totally leaking memory and leaving the passed-in parameter NULL back in `main()`. Even pointers are passed by-value in C. If you want to modify the address one holds (and you do), you have to pass it by-addrss (i.e. a pointer-to-pointer).

Comment: @WhozCraig I was just trying to make sure it was because of garbage data entered into the char*s in sscanf. But regardless of initialization, I don't even deal with putting information into the structs until much farther down. Right now it's messign up with strcasecmp after reading data.

Comment: Okay so that might be my issue here then? If I initialized in  main you think it would work?

Comment: @user2353398 I'm posting an answer, and the depressing part it, its so core to the code you're writing I can offer no guarantees it is going to "fix" everything; only that it will fix `init()`. You'll have to take it from there.

Comment: @WhozCraig YOU WERE RIGHT YOU ARE SAVING MY LIFE LIKE 10 TIMES OVER. Man C and Compilers is hard.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I don't mind. As long as there is a sliver of hope I'll keep fighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to turn into a giant debugging session, but this is a fundamental problem in your code and has to be resolved before anything else.

```
void init(Instruction head) // note: passed by-value
{
    head = (Instruction) malloc(sizeof(struct Command));
    // etc...
}
```

Consider this: Take a function that you want to use to set a caller-side `int` variable to some value. You'd do it like this:

```
void func(int *p) // note by-address
{
    *p = 42;
}

// caller code
int a = 0;
func(&a); // pass address
```

Pointers are no different. Pointers hold addresses, but the also *have* addresses (this distinguishes them from arrays, btw, which simply *are* addresses). Your `init()` should look like this:

```
void init(Instruction* head) // note: by address
{
    Instruction p = malloc(sizeof(struct Command)); // note no cast
    p->->opcode = 0;
    p->next = NULL;
    // etc...

    // save result to address given by out-parameter
    *head = p;
}
```

Caller side:

```
Instruction head = NULL;
init(&head); // note address passed.
```

This should get you going.

---

**Side Note**

C programmers *like* asterisks. Really. Not kidding. They're giant flags in the code that scream from the mountain-tops "THIS IS A POINTER". Hiding that in a `typedef` is **rarely** helpful. In fact there are only three cases I've seen where they are arguably legitimate, and one of those is a red-herring.

1. An abtract opaque "handle" type for a library API. This is common and completely legitimate.
2. Function pointer types. Often used to ensure proper types are being used for different "callback" mechanisms ( `typedef int (*callback_type)(void);` for example).
3. Avoiding incorrect variable declarations on the same line. (this is the red herring).

The third of those is best demonstrated:

```
int* a,b; // declares one pointer-to-int, one int.

typedef int *int_ptr;
int_ptr a,b; // declared two pointers-to-int.
```

While that may seem helpful, it really isn't. The compiler will bomb when you try this later in the code:

```
*b = something;
```

So you'll catch yourself regardless (usually).

Bottom line, don't be afraid of asterisks. They're there to help you see things clearer if you let them.

Comment: This is taking into account that Instruction is typedef'd as a pointer to Command still right? So wouldn't:
   Instruction *p = malloc(sizeof(struct Command)); 
Be bad? cause I'm setting the pointer to a pointer to a pointers size?

Comment: @user2353398 yes, i'll update it. thanks for catching it. Like I said. I *hate* typedef pointer types.

Comment: You have to change your prototype as well. And as I said, this isn't going to turn into a step-by-step debugging session. The code above is very specific and calls out a fundamental flaw in how you were doing this. The result was invoking undefined behavior all over the place. It isn't going to be fixed in a couple of minutes and some text replacements. It will take some time. Personally I'd start with a separate program  that unit-tests the snot out of your linked list code before trying to integrate it into this. It needs to be *solid* or none of this is going to work.